# What's the best way to commit PostgreSQL data to git?

Tags: postgresql, git

I use docker compose to save PostgreSQL data locally:

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: aimd-postgres
    environment:
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    image: postgres:16
    ports:
      - '65432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./database:/data/postgres
version: '3.5'
```

I want to commit this data to git (it is very little data, but it helps to keep my project simple).

A slight inconvenience is that postgres creates many files and git asks to commit them all individually:

```
    modified:   database/base/5/1247
    modified:   database/base/5/1249
    modified:   database/base/5/1259
    modified:   database/base/5/16406
    modified:   database/base/5/2224
    modified:   database/base/5/24649
    modified:   database/base/5/24650
    modified:   database/base/5/24656
    modified:   database/base/5/2579
    modified:   database/base/5/2604
    modified:   database/base/5/2606
    modified:   database/base/5/2608
    modified:   database/base/5/2609
    modified:   database/base/5/2610
    modified:   database/base/5/2620
    modified:   database/base/5/2656
    modified:   database/base/5/2657
    modified:   database/base/5/2658
    modified:   database/base/5/2659
    modified:   database/base/5/2662
    modified:   database/base/5/2663
    modified:   database/base/5/2664
    modified:   database/base/5/2665
    modified:   database/base/5/2666
    modified:   database/base/5/2667
    modified:   database/base/5/2673
    modified:   database/base/5/2674
    modified:   database/base/5/2675
    modified:   database/base/5/2678
    modified:   database/base/5/2679
    modified:   database/base/5/2699
    modified:   database/base/5/2701
    modified:   database/base/5/2702
    modified:   database/base/5/2703
    modified:   database/base/5/2704
    modified:   database/base/5/3455
    modified:   database/base/5/5002
```

I would ideally like to find either a way for postgres to store data all in one or fewer files, or somehow indicate to git that the entire directory should be committed as unit, i.e. do not break it down.

I've tried searching for postgres documentation and git, but didn't find how to do this.

Comment: ...databases don't belong in `git`. Instead, commit your database object's source-code (`CREATE TABLE`, `VIEW` and `PROCEDURE` definitions and seed data scripts).

Comment: In this case, I actually want to commit the entire database. I read that git can store large files so it should not be a problem.

Comment: You're thinking of Git LFS, but that [requires an extension](https://git-lfs.com/), it's not built-in to `git`. And just because you can, doesn't mean that _you should_...

Comment: Dump the DB to a text file using `pg_dump` and version control the text dump. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12516565/7976758

Comment: What PhD said. Put it in text rather than dealing with binary files