# Unable to complete Git Push : PHP Memory Exhausted?

Tags: php, git, memory, git-push

I tried to push a branch to my remote repository but could not.
The error message said:

```
    git -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags --set-upstream origin abcd:abcd 
    Pushing to https://[userid]@[repository address]/git/[projid].git
    POST git-receive-pack (567 bytes)
    remote: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 662439121 bytes) in /home1/html/[repository center name]/www/include/Snoopy.class.php on line 1156        
    remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/unit04        
    Completed with errors, see above
```

536870912 bytes == 512MB. I checked /etc/php.ini.default and checked memory_limit but it was 128MB.

I noticed someone else experienced [memory problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214321/git-gc-using-excessive-memory-unable-to-complete). Is my problem same as this person's?

Good day,

KW

Answer (score 1):

Git isn't written in PHP, so you need to figure out why it's calling that file. Your memory issue isn't in git, it's in Snoopy.class.php.

I'm guessing it's a [git hook](http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html).