# When I export mercurial to git, why is the result so large?

Tags: git, mercurial

I have an old mercurial repository that I am exporting to git using hg-fast-export.  It is 115MB.  When I run hg-fast-export [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037787/convert-mercurial-project-to-git), the resulting git repository is 663M.  Any idea why that would be?

Comment: I don't know what the mercurial import script does, but try running `git gc` or `git repack` (there are a variety of options to each you may need to experiment with) to see if that shrinks things.

Comment: git repack said there was nothing to pack.  git gc made it 100MB bigger...

Comment: `git repack -a -d --depth=250 --window=250` is my normal repo shrinking command. Depending on what the import script did you may have extra refs and/or reflogs that need to be cleaned up first. But you can try the `repack` first.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was
`git gc --aggressive` which I actually got from an article where Linus Torvalds said it was a bad idea but his command didn't work and this one did.

https://web.archive.org/web/20071231101230/https://metalinguist.wordpress.com/2007/12/06/the-woes-of-git-gc-aggressive-and-how-git-deltas-work/

I also had to change the memory usage parameters for packing, as described here:

[Is there a way to limit the amount of memory that "git gc" uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095737/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-amount-of-memory-that-git-gc-uses)