# Issue with V8 fetching on Raspberry Pie 3B

Tags: raspberry-pi, v8

I'm trying to get and build V8 on RPi Model 3B (Debian GNU/Linux 11 bullseye):

```
fetch v8
```

But receiving error in the very end:

```
[0:26:08] Resolving deltas:  98% (19668/19907)
[0:26:58] Resolving deltas:  98% (19669/19907)
[0:26:58] error: index-pack died of signal 9
[0:26:58] fatal: index-pack failed
----------------------------------------
Error: Command 'git -c core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g fetch origin --no-tags' returned non-zero exit status 128 in /home/lfk/git/v8/v8


Warnings:
Conflicting directory /home/lfk/git/v8/v8 moved to /home/lfk/git/v8/_bad_scm/v8uqta58r4.

Subprocess failed with return code 1.
```

Fetch rerun doesn't helps (tryed it several times).

A tried also:

```
Fetch --nohooks --no-history v8
```

but it doesn't helps as well

Comment: A web search for "index-pack died of signal 9" suggests that this _might_ be an out-of-memory problem. How much memory does your raspi have?

Comment: @jmrk, it has 1024 Mb onboard

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095737/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-amount-of-memory-that-git-gc-uses help? (Try limits that fit your free memory.) Also, if you have a more powerful machine available, you might have a better experience by cross-compiling V8. Building on a RasPi is possible (I tried on a RasPi 4 with 4GB memory) but takes hours.

Comment: @jmrk, yes I tried this git limits, but error still  occurs... I have another machine with Ubuntu 22 onboard and V8 builds perfect on it, but unfortunately I have to do the same on RPi.